# How to swap key and value of an object using jq?

Tags: json, key, jq

Using jq I would like to inverse a json object so that the property becomes the value and the value becomes the key.

Source:

```
{ 
    "123": "Foobar"
    "567": "Poit"
}
```

Goal:

```
{ 
    "Foobar": "123"
    "Poit": "567"
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your particular case:

```
to_entries | map( {(.value) : .key } ) | add
```

More robustly:

```
to_entries | map( {(.value|tostring) : .key } ) | add
```

Or if you prefer:

```
with_entries( .key as $k | .key = (.value|tostring) | .value = $k )
```

Caveat: all these are potentially lossy.

Answer (score 9):

If some keys have equal values then probably you would like to get an array of keys as value:

```
to_entries
| map( {(.value) : {(.key):null} } )
| reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)
| to_entries
| map({key:.key, value:(.value|keys)})
| from_entries
```

input:

```
{
  "key1": "val0",
  "key2": "val1",
  "key3": "val1"
}
```

output:

```
{
  "val0": ["key1"],
  "val1": ["key2", "key3"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use an approach similar to @peak's answer but without using the `add` method

First use `to_entries` to get an output like this:

```
-> to_entries
Output:
[
  {
    "key": "123",
    "value": "Foobar"
  },
  {
    "key": "567",
    "value": "Poit"
  }
]
```

Then use `map` to swap the keys with values:

```
-> to_entries | map({key: .value|tostring, value: .key})  ###**tostring** method converts a number to string since keys can't be numbers
Output:
[
  {
    "key": "Foobar",
    "value": "123"
  },
  {
    "key": "Poit",
    "value": "567"
  }
]
```

Finally use `from_entries` to remove the `key/value` and return back to the original format:

```
-> to_entries | map({key: .value|tostring, value: .key}) | from_entries
Output:
{
  "Foobar": "123",
  "Poit": "567"
}
```