# Re-organize json using jq

Tags: json, jq

I want to re-organize a json using jq.
My json is like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "Robin"
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": "id3",
    "name": "Jane"
  }
]
```

I want to have an output as :

```
[
  {
    "Robin": "id1"
  },
  {
    "John": "id2"
  },
  {
    "Jane": "id3"
  }
]
```

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did your attempt fail?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to swap key and value of an object using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847936/how-to-swap-key-and-value-of-an-object-using-jq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yu need:

```
cat data1.jtxt | jq 'to_entries|map({(.value.name):(.value.id)})'
```

My output:

```
[
      {
        "Robin": "id1"
      },
      {
        "John": "id2"
      },
      {
        "Jane": "id3"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand how was this command so difficult to find

```
[.[] | {(.id):.name}] | add
```

gives you:

```
{
  "id1": "Robin",
  "id2": "John",
  "id3": "Jane"
}
```

If you want to keep the "object separation" just remove the `| add`

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226370/jq-print-key-and-value-for-each-entry-in-an-object) somehow led me to it.