# How can I use jq to invert a map and create lists for duplicate values?

Tags: json, jq, inverse-relationship

Let's say I have a JSON map like so:

```
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": "3",
  "c": "2",
  "d": "1"
}
```

How can I invert it and create lists for duplicates. So end up with this:

```
{
 "1": [ "a", "d"],
 "2": "c",
 "3": "b" 
}
```

or

```
{
 "1": [ "a", "d"],
 "2": ["c"],
 "3": ["b"] 
}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to swap key and value of an object using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847936/how-to-swap-key-and-value-of-an-object-using-jq)

Answer (score 2):

Since a JSON object has an obvious interpretation as a mathematical function, it has a relational inverse that is, as suggested by the second possibility mentioned in the question, quite similar to a JSON object with array-valued keys.

Unfortunately, since the keys in a JSON object must all be JSON strings, any "inverse" mapping of JSON objects to JSON objects must either restrict the domain, or come with a caveat.

The following definition eschews restricting the domain in favor of the caveat that it actually returns the inverse of `map_values(tostring)`; that is, in effect, it treats all values of the input JSON object as strings.  For example, it does not distinguish between {"k":1} and {"k": "1"}.

#### `inverseMapping`

The following implementation avoids the sorting entailed by `group_by`:

```
# Input: a JSON object, $in, viewed as a mapping of keys to strings;
# Output: a JSON object, all values of which are arrays.
# The output represents the inverse relation defined
# by $in|map_values(tostring)
def inverseMapping: 
  reduce to_entries[] as $pair ({};
    .[$pair.value|tostring] += [$pair.key]);
```

Example: Using the JSON data in the question, the output would be:

```
{"1":["a","d"],"3":["b"],"2":["c"]}
```

#### `quasiInverseMapping`

The following function implements the transformation envisioned by the first possibility mentioned in the question:

```
# Input: a JSON object, $in;
# Output: a JSON object, $out, representing the inverse relation
#         as above but such that:  
#         if ($in[$key]|tostring) is a distinct value, $v,
#         then $out[$v] == $key
def quasiInverseMapping:
  reduce to_entries[] as $pair ({};
    ($pair.value|tostring) as $v
     | if (.[$v]|type) == "array" then .[$v] += [$pair.key]
       elif .[$v] then .[$v] = [.[$v], $pair.key]
       else .[$v] = $pair.key
       end) ;
```

Example: Using the JSON data in the question, the output would be:

```
{"1":["a","d"],"3":"b","2":"c"}
```